# ADB Over Wifi Connection

Tags: wi-fi, adb

Suppose my phone is connected using adb over wifi....will I have to repeat the process of connecting the usb cable if I switch to my carrier network by chance?...or will it remain forever and I can just reconnect wirelessly by using
adb connect

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

when you switch network - you will need to do it again.

Also after turning off the phone you will need to connect it by the adb again.